# Android How to create rain like animtion?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation

I want to create a animation with some dots and they are falling from top to bottom. For that I am using a translate animation which moves the dots images from top to bottom. But I want this to be continuous meaning the animation should repeat itself.

I have to create a animation with some dots and they are falling from top to bottom i will post gif animation  file , which is my requirement , please anyone guide me how to create this one?
it starts with FadeIn animation it is running fine in my code  and then the dots moving in continuous Motion from TOP TO BOTTOM as in gif i have posted it is not working in my code i have created 14 Linearlayouts they contains 7 texviews Horizontally with VISIBILITY.GONE in Oncreate i am changing its VISIBILITY to VISIBLE and starting FADE IN animation  and  i will post my code , please anyone guide me? 
MY REQUIREMNET
[rain_like_animation](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2811593/6410268/e629f562-be93-11e4-85ae-cfddb19d7c0c.gif)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
 LinearLayout move_animation, move_animation1, move_animation2,
                move_animation3, move_animation4, move_animation5;
        Display display;
        Point size2;
        int width1, height1;
        // Animation
        Animation animFadein;
        TranslateAnimation translateanimation;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            size2 = new Point();
            display.getSize(size2);
            width1 = size2.x;
            height1 = size2.y;

            move_animation   = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.move_animation);
            move_animation1  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.move_animation1);
            move_animation2  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.move_animation2);
            move_animation3  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.move_animation3);


            // load the animation
            animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
            // set animation listener
            animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

            // (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
            translateanimation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f, height1);
            translateanimation.setDuration(3000);
            translateanimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            translateanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            translateanimation.setFillAfter(false);
            translateanimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("onAnimationStart", "onAnimationStart");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("onAnimationRepeat", "onAnimationRepeat");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("onAnimationEnd", "onAnimationEnd");
                }
            });
            move_animation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            move_animation1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            move_animation2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            move_animation3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // start the Fadein animation
            // =============================================
            // =============================================
            move_animation.startAnimation(animFadein);
            move_animation1.startAnimation(animFadein);
            move_animation2.startAnimation(animFadein);
            move_animation3.startAnimation(animFadein);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Take any action after completing the animation
            // start the translate animation when fade-in stops
            move_animation.startAnimation(translateanimation);
            move_animation1.startAnimation(translateanimation);
            move_animation2.startAnimation(translateanimation);
            move_animation3.startAnimation(translateanimation);
            }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashimage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/move_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="7" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/move_animation1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/move_animation2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/move_animation3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232268/1881611

Comment: please could you explore it more, i am not understanding it completely

Comment: no it does not meet with my requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download this library https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

Add this to your project dependency

then

```
new ParticleSystem(RainActivity.this, 80, R.drawable.rain_drop, 10000)
    .setSpeedByComponentsRange(0f, 0f, 0.05f, 0.1f)
    .setAcceleration(0.00005f, 90)
    .emitWithGravity(findViewById(R.id.cloud), Gravity.BOTTOM, 8);
```

[It will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBIFV.gif)

Comment: I have created a demo using this library but when i run the demo with LeonidsLib.jar it is giving me error Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Could you please post logcat of errror?

Comment: i am getting error during compilition RainAnimation] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
Origin 1: E:\WORKSPACE_GIT_INTEGRATIONAS ON 24th FEB\workspace\RainAnimation\bin\resources.ap_
Origin 2: E:\WORKSPACE_GIT_INTEGRATIONAS ON 24th FEB\workspace\RainAnimation\libs\LeonidsLib.jar

Comment: now demo  is running but it does not meet with my requirement as you can see in the gif i posted All the items of the image are using the same direction, speed and size ?

Comment: @IshRoid, I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol rain_drop"